# An explanation of Virtual Assistant Test projects

Tags: botframework

I am trying to understand the Test projects that get generated in a Virtual Assistant bot or Skill so that I can apply that approach to the custom dialogs and bot logic I am developing.

Is there blog post or write up that specifically speaks to how those Virtual Assistant Test projects work?

Answer (score 0):

@3-putt if by "Virtual Assistant Test projects", I'm assuming you're talking about the unit tests that test the dialog in the VA bot?

If so, then here's the down low on that:

- By popular demand, the Bot Framework SDK Team actually just released the bot Testing Framework in v4.5 a couple days ago on 7/10/19. We wanted to provide guidance/framework for developers to unit test the dialog responses in the bots they're building

You can see the Framework's Integration in the samples, currently in the corebot-updates branch:

- C#:  https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/corebot-updates/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot.tests
- JS: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/corebot-updates/samples/javascript_nodejs/13.core-bot/tests

These samples should be merged next week, but you can get a sneak peak at the future of testing dialogs now.

Docs regarding that sample and the Testing Framework are also expected to release next week as well in learn.microsoft.com (they're currently written, however not released to public yet).

---

Currently the unit tests in the VA are not from the new testing framework, since VA has not updated to 4.5 yet (again, just released it a couple days ago), however they definitely will update to the most recently version of Bot Framework in the future, and will also implement the new testing framework.

---

TL;DR **look for docs on core-bot or bot testing framework sometime next week :)**